# What a face/facet of a cardboard box is called? a piece of wall?

Tags: terminology

In geometry, a [cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube) is a three-dimensional solid object bounded by six square faces, facets or sides, with three meeting at each vertex. A cardboard box could be viewed as a cube.

[image]

A cube has 6 faces, 12 edges, and 8 vertices. What a face/facet of a cardboard box is called in daily life? a piece of wall?

Comment: You shouldn’t use “a piece of wall” here. The “side” of a box is a complete “wall” of the box, not just a “piece” of it.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Thanks for your comments. so, it is just a **wall**, right?

Comment: Yes. The four vertical parts can be called either a “wall” or a “side“.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Thank you so much! What is this type of top called, which distinguishes from [another type of top](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/235918/is-the-bottom-of-a-box-does-not-have-a-part-that-tuck-in-to-seal-the-box-still-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: There is no particular name here, just some possible descriptions, such as (for the box pictured here): “the four flaps forming the top of the box”. And for your other picture: “the flap forming the top of the box”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People refer to a side or wall of the box, the top and the bottom.

They might be more specific by talking about the longer or shorter side/wall.

The bits at the top and the bottom that tuck in to seal the box are called the flaps.

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=cardboard+box+flaps
https://www.themanufacturer.com/articles/how-a-cardboard-box-is-made/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is only the type of the top of the box shown in the post called the flaps? Could any other types of the top of a box be called the flaps?

Comment: The flaps are the parts at the top and bottom that fold in to seal the box.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you please take a look at this [related post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/235921/103381) ?