# What exactly A flap is in the context of a cardboard box?

Tags: terminology

per this [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/235913/103381)

> The bits at the top and the bottom that tuck in to seal the box are called the flaps.

are there 4 flaps in the image shown below?

[image]

or the whole top is A flap?

Are these 4 parts also flaps?

[image]

My concern is if only the part that could be tucked in called flap, because I had got this [answer](http://The%20bits%20at%20the%20top%20and%20the%20bottom%20that%20tuck%20in%20to%20seal%20the%20box%20are%20called%20the%20flaps.) (exactly the same one at the beginning of this post) originally.

> The bits at the top and the bottom that tuck in to seal the box are called the flaps.

Answer (score 3):

You are being too much of a language lawyer! A flap is any kind of loose, flat structure. The parts marked 1-4 are flaps. And the lid of the box is a big flap (until it is secured into place).

So what is, or isn't a "flap" can and will change according to the context. Since the main purpose of the large top flap is "to cover the box" you would probably ususally call that part the "lid". The lid is secured by several flaps: a large one that also forms part of the front of the box and four small flaps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are these [4 parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny0EX.png) also flaps?