# What is the gap/crack/flaw in the top of a cardboard box called?

Tags: terminology

per this [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/235913/103381)

> The bits at the top and the bottom that tuck in to seal the box are called the flaps.

what is the gap/crack/flaw pointed out by red arrow shown below (img_1) called?

[image]

is the part that is labeled blue shown below (img_2) also a slot?

[image]

Another concern is the hole/slot in img_1 is hollowed out while the one in img_2 is not.

Comment: What would you call it? (in your native language) Have you used a bilingual dictionary to research this?  There is almost certainly no specfic word that mean "the  slot in the top of a cardboard box" so the generic term that your bilingual dictionary would give is probably the right word. What is the actual context that you are using this in? You probably don't need a specific word, since context can clarify.

Comment: @JamesK has used the word that I would suggest, which is _slot_ .

Comment: @JamesK It is called a **hole** in my native language.

Comment: @zghqh That is the answer!  It is a hole.

Answer (score 1):

The feature indicated in img_1 would most likely be called a hole or slot. It could be called a gap as well, but that is more commonly taken to mean the space between two objects or features rather than a space or cut-out *inside* an object.

The blue circle in img_2 surrounds something that could be called a gap or slot. Calling it a hole is less suitable because it is a space between two objects (two pieces of cardboard) instead of a cut-out in a object like the one in img_1, but I could imagine someone calling it a hole anyway.

I agree with James that both features would never be called "flaws" (because they were intentionally designed as part of the boxes), and I would also say that "crack" is unsuitable. In the technical and common definition of the term, a crack is something that forms as a result of mechanical damage, like the one shown below in a sheet of metal. The hole in img_1 was intentionally cut out and did not develop as a result of mechanical stress.

[image: Elliptical crack with dimensions labelled]

Answer (score 0):

That is a hole. It could also be called a gap, or a slot. These are all generic words. There is no specific word for the "hole in the lid of a cardboard box".

It isn't a flaw, because a flaw is something unwanted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you almostly, with only one concern, that is, the hole/slot in img_1 is hollowed out while the one in img_2 is not.

Comment: Consider all the possible shapes for a hole. There can't be a word for each one. Now, the word 'slot' is more specific than 'hole'. It means a hole that may be elongated, that is designed for the insertion of something else, for example, a 'tab'.